# How to make Ubuntu to detect my secondary (a CRT with a laptop) display?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, display, external-display, crt

How to make Ubuntu (10.10, today daily iso build) to detect my secondary display (a 18'' Dell CRT attached to a laptop with Intel 82852/855GM graphics)? Currently it "sees" only one "unknown" 0Hz 1024x768 display (which results in my CRT to show the same as the laptop's panel does, but using its native mode, so only part of its surface us used). Everything used to work fine with Arch Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. The solution is to combine these 2 answers: [how to install Intel graphics driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4658/how-to-install-intel-82852-855gm-driver-on-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat/4659#4659) and [how to configure X](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-x-org-config-file-in-ubuntu-10-10-how-to-configure-x-there/4663#4663) in Ubuntu 10.10.